# Backone relational subModelTypes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I’m using in my app awesome trio: Backbone + Backbone Relational + Marionette.

Currently, I’ve got some troubles with creating polymorphic relation.

Here is simplified version of code I’m currently using.

```
class MyApp.Conversation extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot: "/api/v0/conversations"
  relations: [
    {
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "members"
      relatedModel: MyApp.User
    }
  ] 



class MyApp.User extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot: "/api/v0/users"
  # subModelTypes: {
  #   "Teacher": MyApp.Teacher
  #   "Student": MyApp.Student
  # }

class MyApp.Teacher extends MyApp.User

class MyApp.Student extends MyApp.User
```

When I’ve got `subModelTypes` section commented out (as I’ve pasted here) everything works OK (apart from that all members of conversation are Users, instead of Teachers/Students). When  I add that `subModelTypes` into my model, I’m getting following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object` in [Line 1638](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/blob/0.8.6/backbone-relational.js#L1638)

I looked at example code for subModels from backbone-relational homepage, and I can’t find anything I’m doing wrong here.

I would be very greatful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this myself.  This is [CoffeeScript-related, as detailed here](http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-setup).  You need to call `MyApp.User.setup()` after the class definition.